Invalid JWT token in ASP.NET Core
I am developing a JWT-based authentication and role-based authorization system with ASP.NET Core. When users log in, a JWT token is created and there is a Role claim in this token.
However, when I send a request to an endpoint where I use [Authorize(Roles = "User")], I constantly get a "401 Unauthorized" error. Please help me.
public IDataResult<string> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
{
    var userToCheck = _userService.GetByMail(userForLoginDto.Email).Data;

    if (userToCheck == null)
    {
        return new ErrorDataResult<string>("User not found");
    }

    if (userToCheck.Password != userForLoginDto.Password)
    {
        return new DataResult<string>(null, false, "Invalid email or password");
    }

    var userClaims = _userDal.GetClaims(userToCheck);
    var token = _tokenHelper.GenerateToken(userToCheck, userClaims);

    return new DataResult<string>(token, true, "Login successful");
}

public string GenerateToken(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email) };

    foreach (var operationClaim in operationClaims)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, operationClaim.Name));
    }

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["TokenOptions:SecurityKey"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["TokenOptions:Issuer"],
        audience: _configuration["TokenOptions:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

[HttpGet("GetAll")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var cars = _carService.GetAll();

    if (cars.Success)
        return Ok(cars);

    return BadRequest(cars);
}

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["TokenOptions:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = configuration["TokenOptions:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["TokenOptions:SecurityKey"]))
        };
    });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();



How and where do you call GetAll() ?

try to change ClaimTypes.Role to "role"?

ı tried but doesnt work @TinyWang

swagger postman @maximelian1986

You may be sending jwt token with wrong parameter. For ex in Postman, do you send it in body or after you get authenticated, you adding it to authentication token settings?

First unlock it with Bearer {token} in Swagger. I execute directly. and I get 401 error. In Postman, even though I give the token in the Authorization settings, it gives me a 401 in my getAll method. @maximelian1986

You might take a look at this case which might be helpful to you. My idea is that you shall need an AuthorizationHandler for validating the role claim.

Normally speaking, we need to add policy for custom authorization scheme, in your scenario, it's checking the role claim("role" and ClaimTypes.Role) is different. ClaimTypes.Role is usedwhen using asp.net core default identity. If we integrate default identity into .net core app, we can assign role to users, so that we can use [Authorize(Roles = "xx")] to stop users who doesn't have corresponding roles to visit the secured endpoint, but this is different than JWT auth. JWT auth scheme doesn't have such default configuration, and we have to create custom policy based auth to validate claim.
